# Understanding the Whitehead group equivalent classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I’m having trouble thinking about the elements of the Whitehead group. For instance what do the elements of $K_{1} \mathbb{R}=GL(\mathbb{R})/E(\mathbb{R})$ look like?

If we quotient the group of invertible matrices by the elementary matrices, then what’s left? Milnor says $K_{1} \mathbb{R}=U(\mathbb{R}) \bigoplus SK_{1}(\mathbb{R})$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R} - {0}$. But I’m not sure how?

My current understanding is that the cosets of $K_{1} \mathbb{R}$ are determined by matrices that have the same determinant because some combination of elementary matrices is equivalent to them. And the determinant map is the isomorphism to consider.

- $E(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the elementary matrices
- $SK(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the special linear group
- $U(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the units of $\mathbb{R}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A good place to study the Whitehead group is Weibel's book on Algebraic K-Theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a field $k$, the group $K_1(k)$ is not particularly interesting; like you implied above, it's just $k^\times$. The proof is really just linear algebra, showing that $SL_n(k)$ is generated by elementary matrices, or even Gaussian elimination. A less trivial result due to Bass, Milnor, and Serre is that the ring of integers ${\cal O}_k$ of a number field $k$ also has $K_1({\cal O}_k) = {\cal O}_k^\times$.

As for what an element of $K_1(\mathbb{R})$ looks like, it's exactly what you wrote: an element of $GL(\mathbb{R})$ modulo $E(\mathbb{R})$. It's just an ordinary quotient group.